# The quantisation of the harmonic oscillator applied to the free Klein-Gordon field

Tags: quantum-field-theory, harmonic-oscillator, fourier-transform, klein-gordon-equation

In [David Tong's lecture notes](https://www.damtp.cam.ac.uk/user/tong/qft/qft.pdf) on quantum field theory, at the bottom of page 23, we are applying the quantisation of the harmonic oscillator to the field to obtain expressions for the field operators in terms of ladder operators.

If we write the field $\phi(\vec x,t)$ as its Fourier transform: $$\phi(\vec x,t)=\int \frac{\text d^3p}{(2\pi)^3}e^{i\vec p\cdot\vec x}\phi(\vec p,t),$$ and then expand the field in terms of the ladder operators we obtain: $$\phi(\vec x,t)=\int \frac{\text d^3p}{(2\pi)^3}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\omega_\vec p}}\left[a_\vec pe^{i\vec p\cdot\vec x}+a^\dagger_\vec pe^{-i\vec p\cdot\vec x}\right],$$ My problem is where the negative sign in the second exponential comes from, I can't really even provide a guess, since I *want* to say that we're just substituting in what is essentially the position operator from the regular quantum harmonic oscillator: $$\hat x=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\omega}}(\hat a+\hat a^\dagger).$$

Comment: The dagger $\dagger$ also takes the complex conjugate of this exponential.

Comment: @NDewolf But the $e^{i\vec p\cdot \vec x}$ is already in the integral, where do we take the conjugate of it?

Comment: I wouldn't stare to much at it. It is just an analogy, so you take an ansatz of the form $a+a^\dagger$ (with exponentials included). Note that it is also required by the reality condition of the real KG-field.

Comment: @NDewolf Ah ok, looking at P&S I see what you mean about the reality condition. I won't overthink it too hard then, thanks for your input :)